Door knobs for double doors
We changed our bathroom door into a double door since it is a small bathroom and the door was taking up space. I'm trying to think about how to connect door knobs. They won't be knobs that turn. We are using a slide bolt to lock the door. I want knobs on both sides of both doors. I found dummy knobs but how can I attach a knob on both sides? Is there a kind of screw or bolt that can be finished or capped on one side to go through two dummy knobs? I hope that makes sense.

I would just use regular door knobs without the latch.  Nice and simple.

@crip659 the latch assembly is what usually keeps the door handle centered on the hole in the door

@jsotola  That is with the large diameter common hole.  Just need two small holes for the screws and maybe an inch hole for any centre stuff that sticks in.  Measurements are much more important.

What are the motions like for someone exiting the bathroom?

You just push through the door. I want dummy knobs that don't turn. Just like a cabinet or a closet.

@MichelleHill so get some doorknobs or cabinet knobs that use a single central bolt, and some hanger bolts that match that size bolt.  Screw one into each side of the door.

Dummy knobs are normally attached with two woodscrews.  To install two dummy knobs on opposite sides you can replace the woodscrews with machine screws and nuts. Use locknuts to keep them from working loose.  The machine screws will have to be long enough to go through the door and the two backing plates, with room left for the nuts, but not so long that they interfere with the cover plate that goes over the mount.
These parts are available at any hardware store in various lengths, diameters, and head styles.  Just take the dummy knobs with you, along with the exact thickness of the door.
As an alternative, if I was doing this, I would just install them on each side of the doors with the standard wood screws.  There's really no need for a single fastener that goes through both knobs.

yeah, or sexbolts

So you'll have a knob and a backing plate, with exposed nuts, on both sides of the door?

@Huesmann - No, the backing plate and mounting screws get covered with a decorative plate.  The machine screws would have screw heads on one side and nuts on the other, both covered by the decorative plate.

You can get double-ended knobs.


I don't want to drill a hole large enough through the door because I have nothing to make a hole that large and these rods are too long for the door I used which is a solid pine bifold door.

no 3/8" drill? no hacksaw?

@MichelleHill perhaps if you added some photos so we know exactly what kind of door you're dealing with...
